# Node-Red: Passing array of checkboxes as node property

Tags: node.js, node-red

I'm creating a custom node-red node, and I want to do the following: in the node UI, I have several checkboxes for the user to select. When the user checks their desired boxes, and saves the node configuration, I want to pass a dictionary-like object representing the selected checkboxes to node's JS file. It looks something like this:

The HTML file:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    RED.nodes.registerType('my-node',{
        category: 'function',
        color: '#a6bbcf',
        defaults: {
            name: { value:"" },
            mapOfCheckboxes: { value: {} }
        },
        inputs:1,
        outputs:1,
        icon: "file.png",
        label: function() {
            return this.name||"my-node";
        }
    });
</script>

<script type="text/html" data-template-name="my-node">
    <div class="form-row">
        <label for="node-input-name"><i class="fa fa-tag"></i> Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="node-input-name" placeholder="Name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <label for="vehicle1"> I have a bike</label><br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="node-input-mapOfCheckboxes" name="vehicle1" value="Bike">
        <label for="vehicle2"> I have a car</label><br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="node-input-mapOfCheckboxes" name="vehicle2" value="Car">
        <label for="vehicle3"> I have a boat</label><br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="node-input-mapOfCheckboxes" name="vehicle3" value="Boat">
    </div>
</script>

<script type="text/html" data-help-name="my-node">
    <p>node description</p>
</script>
```

How I want the mapOfCheckboxes to look (assuming all 3 checkboxes have been checked):

```
mapOfCheckboxes = {
'vehicle-1': 'Bike',
'vehicle-2': 'Car',
'vehicle-3': 'Boat',
};
```

The JS file:

```js
module.exports = function(RED) {
    function MyNode(config) {
        RED.nodes.createNode(this,config);
        this.mapOfCheckboxes = config.mapOfCheckboxes;
        var node = this;

        // do stuff here with the checkbox key:value pairs in mapOfCheckboxes

        node.on('input', function(msg) {
            node.send(msg);
        });
    }
    RED.nodes.registerType("my-node",LowerCaseNode);
}
```

So my confusion is how can I:

1. create this mapOfCheckboxes that has a key:value pair for each selected checkbox
2. when user saves the node config, save this map to the node property mapOfCheckboxes
3. pass the mapOfCheckboxes to the JS file so I can do stuff with the selected checkboxes

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the helper functions in the HTML file.

You need to add an `oneditsave` (and `oneditprepare`) function to the `RED.nodes.registerType()` in the HTML file.

`oneditsave` can be used to build the map

`oneditprepate` can be used to convert the map back into the checkboxes when the user wants to edit the node again later.

Many of the core nodes make use of this,

docs: https://nodered.org/docs/creating-nodes/properties#property-edit-dialog